# PHP date format - Im about ready to break something

Tags: php, date

I've got a standard "US" way of expressing a date - 06/29/1967 or 6-29-67

`strtotime()` and `create_date()` and `date()` or `date_format()` ALL choke on this.

the db is MySQl - storing a date as `yyyy-mm-dd`.

Unfortunately, I can't change my schema to store my dates as epoch time stamps or integers.

Comment: Please consider revising your question. SO is meant for Q&A, not for rants. While we're happy to help, it's likely that your question will be closed if you don't clean it up. Remember, we want the questions on SO to stand alone and be useful to other people (not to mention easy to find). Check out [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) for help on asking questions.

Comment: Just get with the program and use time stamps. I'm not sure what you have against them, but unless you have a specific reason for not using them, you should.

Comment: roger that Drackir

- and seriously regality, I don't have control over the structure, which is WHY i mentiond NOT offering a solution that included structure changes. I should HAVE to change a data type to work with PHP...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will convert your standard date to the format your database requires.

```
date('Y-m-d', strtotime('06/29/1967'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your problem well, but you can use a combination of `date` and `mktime` functions, like that:

```
echo date('Y-m-d', mktime(0, 0, 0, month, day, year));
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php

Answer (score 0):

This is what I've been doing with my PHP/MySQL setup:

Create a date object:
`$date = new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone("UTC"));`

Save date in DB:
`$dateString = $date->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");`

Retrieve date from DB:
$retrievedDateString = 
`$retrievedDate = new DateTime($retrievedDateString, new DateTimeZone("UTC"))`

Answer (score 0):

Actually @Ramy Deeb replied the same thing I was going to, strtotime will convert into a UNIX timestamp almost anything you throw at it, and date will just make it what you need.

To check what strtotime can handle you can check [the date formats for strtotime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php) or the  [full documentation for acceptable formats](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php)

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use [`date_create_from_format`][1] for this as follows:

```
$myDate = date_create_from_format('m/d/Y', '06/29/1967');
```

For 2 digit format the following is the format,

```
$myDate2 = date_create_from_format('n-d-y', '6-29-67');
```

**NOTE:** The above date is interpreted as *29th June 2067* **NOT** *29th June 1967* because oh PHP's interpretation of 2 digit years. I have tested and PHP treats years from:

```
70 - 99   =>  1970 - 1999
00 - 69   =>  2000 - 2069
```

Thus i recommend using four digit year format.
But if you cannot change the data source, then for a date like yours where 69 is 1969, I would convert the year afterwards as per my own condition, like this:

```
// if the date is wrongly interpreted as 2000+, change it to 1900 one
// here I have choosen range '38 - 99' as '1938 - 1999' 
if(date_format($myDate2, 'Y') > 2038)
    date_sub($myDate2, date_interval_create_from_date_string('100 years'));
```

After you have gotten the `$myDate` object with the correct date use `date_format`

```
$db_date_str = date_format($myDate, 'Y-m-d');
```

And insert this into DB.
[1]: https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php